# Selecionar uma parte do banco de dados no R

Tags: banco-de-dados, r

Estou fazendo uma avaliação do banco de dados do portal da transparência que pode ser obtido nesse [link](http://www.portaldatransparencia.gov.br/downloads/servidores.asp#exercicios2016), o problema é que gostaria de selecionar somente uma parte do banco de dados, minha avaliação é somente sobre os dados de professores. Eu poderia fazer uma limpeza dos dados utilizando o Excel, mas gostaria de aprender a fazer no R. Para a leitura dos dados estou usando o seguinte código:

```
library(readr)

df <- read_delim("~/GitHub/Servidores/Setembro/20160930_Cadastro.csv", 
";", escape_double = FALSE, locale = locale(encoding = "ASCII"),
trim_ws = TRUE)

# As únicas colunas que importam são a 3ª (ID do servidor) 
# e a 6ª (remuneração bruta) na planilha de remuneração      

# Renomeando a coluna ID e de Remuneração básica bruta e 
# fazendo um merge no data frame para acrescentar os salários 
# de cada servidor

salarios <-        
read_delim("~/GitHub/Servidores/Setembro/20160930_Remuneracao.csv", ";",
escape_double = FALSE, locale = locale(encoding = "ASCII"),
trim_ws = TRUE) %>% select(3, 6) 
head(salarios)

names(salarios) <- c("ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL", "SALARIO")

names(df) <- str_to_upper(names(df))
df <- merge(df, salarios, by="ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL")
df$x <- 1
```

Feito isso, gostaria de saber como selecionar uma parte do banco de dados, somente a parte relacionada a professores, de forma a estudar o banco de dados somente para estes.

Comment: Visitei o link e não consegui achar os arquivos `20160930_Cadastro.csv` ou `20160930_Remuneracao.csv`. Achei apenas um arquivo chamado `201609_GastosDiretos.csv`. Além disso, se o teu banco de dados tem apenas duas colunas, uma chamada `ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL` e outra `SALARIO`, onde ficaria a informação sobre o cargo do servidor? É em `ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL` mesmo?

Comment: Oi @MarcusNunes, não sei como, mas peguei o link errado! O mesmo já foi corrigido! O banco de dados cadastro possui 42 duas colunas de interesse e acrescentei mais duas que estão no banco de dados das remunerações. Obrigado e desculpa pelo engano!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não consegui ler os dados com os teus comandos originais. Alterei eles para que meu computador conseguisse trabalhar. Se tu consegue ler estes arquivos com os teus comandos originais, ignore esta parte do meu código.

```
setwd("~/GitHub/Servidores/Setembro/")

library(readr)
library(stringr)

cadastro <- read.table(file="20160930_Cadastro.csv", header=TRUE, sep="\t")

df <- read_delim("20160930_Cadastro.csv", "\t", escape_double=FALSE,
locale = locale(encoding = "Latin1"), trim_ws = TRUE)

# As únicas colunas que importam são a 3ª (ID do servidor) 
# e a 6ª (remuneração bruta) na planilha de remuneração      

# Renomeando a coluna ID e de Remuneração básica bruta e 
# fazendo um merge no data frame para acrescentar os salários 
# de cada servidor

salarios <- read_delim("20160930_Remuneracao.csv", "\t", escape_double = FALSE,
locale = locale(encoding = "Latin1"), trim_ws = TRUE) %>% select(3, 6) 

names(salarios) <- c("ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL", "SALARIO")

names(df) <- str_to_upper(names(df))
df <- merge(df, salarios, by="ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL")
df$x <- 1

# selecionar as posicoes no banco de dados df
# que possuem a string 'PROFESSOR' em algum lugar
# (talvez precise refinar isto dependendo
# do objetivo deste trabalho)

professores <- grep("PROFESSOR", df$DESCRICAO_CARGO)

# novo banco de dados apenas com as linhas dos 
# professores (ou melhor, dos servidores cuja
# descricao do cargo possui 'PROFESSOR' em algum 
# momento)

df.professores <- df[professores, ]
```

Comment: Oi @MarcusNunes, ficou ótimo! Já conhecia o pacote string, mas nem pensei nele. Somente para complementar, como existem alguns professores cuja descrição começa com PROF e tem a palavra SUBSTITUTO junto, no banco de dados faltou alguns nomes, então para complementar o seu código acrescentei ao seu comando a palavra SUBSTITUTO, como abaixo:                         
    
    professores <- grep("PROFESSOR|SUBSTITUTO", df$DESCRICAO_CARGO)

Comment: Perfeito. O importante é conseguir o resultado desejado :)